# Text Centered and Button Right Justified

Tags: html, css

How do I make the text appear in the center and the button appear to the right of the box while still being able to nicely scale the screen? Meaning the space between the box and the text will grow when the screen zoomed out and space will shrink when the screen zoomed in.

Here is what I have...

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LEEvl.jpg

Here is what I want to get...

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ncplj.jpg

EDIT: Here is the JSFiddle...

https://jsfiddle.net/d697spr8/1/

```
<div id="outer">
    <div class="topStuff">
        <p>Games</p>
        <div class="dropdownListPg">
            <button class="dropbtn" style="height: 50px; width: 120px">Sort By
                <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
            </button>
            <div class="dropdownListPg-content" style="color: black">
                <a href="index.html"><button style="height: 50px; width: 120px">Alphabetical</button></a>
                <a href="indexDate.html"><button style="height: 50px; width: 120px">Date</button></a>
                <a href="indexUserScore.html"><button style="height: 50px; width: 120px">User Score</button></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
#outer
{
    min-width: 1200px;
}

.topStuff
{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;

    margin: 0;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: 150px;
    margin-right: 150px;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #999999;
}


.dropdownListPg
{
    display: inline;
}

.dropdownListPg .dropbtn
{

}

.dropdownListPg-content
{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;

    width: fit-content;
    height: fit-content;
    overflow-x: hidden;

    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.dropdownListPg-content a
{
    float: none;
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;

    color: black !important;

    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.dropdownListPg-content a:hover
{
    background-color: wheat !important;
}

.dropdownListPg:hover .dropdownListPg-content
{
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `flex` positioning. Also i noticed that you nested `<button></button>` inside `<a></a>` it is considered a bad practise to nest interactive element into another interactive element.

Also there is another variant with `position: absolute` applied to `dropdown`, but in that case `flex` is better.

```css
#outer {
  min-width: 1200px;
}

.topStuff {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 150px;
  margin-right: 150px;
  background-color: #999999;
}

.holder {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}

.holder--align--right {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.dropdownListPg {
  position: relative;
}

.dropdownListPg-content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.dropdownListPg-content a {
  display: block;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdownListPg-content a:hover {
  background-color: wheat;
}

.dropdownListPg:hover .dropdownListPg-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <div class="topStuff">
    <div class="holder"></div>
    <p>Games</p>
    <div class="holder holder--align--right">
      <div class="dropdownListPg">
        <button class="dropbtn" style="height: 50px; width: 120px">Sort By
          <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
        </button>
        <div class="dropdownListPg-content">
          <a href="index.html">Alphabetical</a>
          <a href="indexDate.html">Date</a>
          <a href="indexUserScore.html">User Score</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: *it is considered a bad practise* --> it's simply invalid and should never be done